# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable - Copied the code directly from the source and got this error. Why?

Tags: python, string, jupyter-notebook

```
    x = np.linspace(0,5,11)
    y = x ** 2
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.plot(x, y, 'r') # 'r' is the color red
    plt.xlabel('X Axis Title Here') #Program stops here and prints str is not callable. 
    plt.ylabel('Y Axis Title Here')
    plt.title('String Title Here')
```

I copied and pasted the code from the source (a Jupyter notebook from an online course) and got the error: str is not callable. Why?

Comment: Seems like xlabel was set to a string in the Jupyter notebook. Can you check the entire notebook and see if there was any place xlabel was set to a string? Also, do you have any import statement anywhere in the notebook? If so, what is it?

Comment: the code you supplied runs fine.

Comment: Thanks, all. Read my answer. For some unknown reason, I closed the notebook, reopened it, ran the program, and it worked. How mankind is able to launch rockets to the moon and back when technology is so fickle, I will never understand.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why, but after I closed the notebook and reopened it and ran the program, it generated the x and y labels and the title. IOW, the program ran just fine, no errors.
This is the second time that this happened, "this" being a program returns an error; I close and reopen the notebook, then run the program, and it works.

Comment: [Welcome to Jupyter Notebooks!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7jiPeIFXb6U)